# LT1084 as Current control Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, emc, current-limiting, emissions

I am using LT1084 as a current control Regulator. Circuit shown below
[image: Fig-1]

Since the transistor Q2 is controlled by a PWM pulse so output voltage of LT1084 is varying as shown below
[image: Fig-2]

Since it is used as current controlled so there is a impact on the input voltage too as shown below
[image: Fig-3]
The supply voltage to LT1084 is 5V and 5V is generated by a switching regulator from 12V input.

Even-though in-between 12V and 5V a switching regulator is placed but the same impact(As on 5V supply shown in fig-3) can be seen on the 12V supply too.

Since the variation is very low around 0.0016V so it is manageable. But i am worried about the EMC and EMI. Is this variation will cause an **impact on EMC/EMI?**

Comment: Looks OK, What's the question?  (The voltage regulator might be happier if it wasn't banged on and off... Just wondering if you could steer the current around the LED and keep a constant current from the regulator.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The question here is that the input voltage is also varying from 4.9982V to 4.9998 (due to on/off pulse at the base of Q2). so is this variation will cause any EMC/EMI impact on the product?

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be a problem.  But I'm no EMI expert.  To get rid of the variation you could put the transistor in parallel with the LED.  So when Q2 is on LED would be off.  That would waste more power as the current source would always be on.

Comment: it depends rising and falling edge times of those pulses......Pulses will have lot of frequencies.....

Answer (score 1):

as i know it will not have to much of a impact as it's quite small. you can add some RC over Q2 to get that negative spike away as that will do more on the EMI.

if you want to get the input better you can also add some CLC (cap-coil-cap) there to filter variation